# simple function gives result as NaNs?

Tags: r

I wrote a simple function but I wonder why I am getting NaNs as results.
Here is the code:

data

```
      en1=c(1,9,5,9,8,7)
      en=c(1,5,4,9,3,7)
      en2=c(1,4,5,4,8,7)
```

function:

run:

```
        err1(en,en1,en2)
```

result:

```
         [1] NaN
           Warning message:
       In sqrt(mean(((pr - ob) * (ob - ref)), na.rm = na.rm)) : NaNs produced
```

Any idea on this please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You obtain `NaN` since the square root of a negative number is undefined (for real numbers).

You might wish to use `abs` in your function:

```
err1 <- function(pr,ob,ref,na.rm=TRUE){
    sqrt(mean(abs((pr-ob)*(ob-ref)), na.rm = na.rm))}     

err1(en,en1,en2)
[1] 1.825742
```